# how to change the value taken from csv of the space with% 20 in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I have a value in a "pro va" csv file that must be passed to a query of a URL "google.com/search?q=pro%20va" I would need to replace the space with% 20 from the variable taken from the csv, how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Space isn't allowed in HTTP GET path or query.

You need to encode query parameters that contain spaces. Some options as below:

1. Check "Encode?" box in "Send Parameters with the Request" input of [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)
2. Wrap your variable in [__urlEncode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__urlencode) function as `${__urlencode(queryTerm)}`